# How can i use dd to inject a byte into the hex file from gdb information

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, hex, reverse

```
=> 0x000000000000121c <+129>:   b8 00 00 00 00  mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000001221 <+134>:   c9  leaveq 
   0x0000000000001222 <+135>:   c3  retq
```

I cannot seem to find the hex address through gdb. Can i even inject a positive return value **b8 01 00 00 00** with the method "printf '\x01' | dd of= ....." into an hex file from the information i get from GDB? i cant seem to find the "seek" value for dd

Comment: I try to identify a unique pattern near the bytes I want to change. I use od to dump the file, find the unique pattern, and figure the offset in the file of the bytes I want to change from that.

Comment: You can of course also do the actual mapping from virtual address to file offsets. For that you'd have to consult the ELF headers but it's usually not worth the trouble, as the pattern search is easier.

Comment: Apologies for asking but how do you perform the pattern search? Because i don’t know what GDB code corresponds with the code from the hex file